# Кастомизация RadioButton

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation

Столкнулся с уже классической проблемой кастомизации радио кнопок. Итак, есть набор иконок. Вопрос: как наиболее оптимально кастомизировать RadioButton с помощью выбора одной из иконок для дальнейшей отправки данных? или есть другой способ реализовать то, что мне нужно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Элементы `radio` и `checkbox` кастомизируются с помощью `label`:

```css
label.custom-radio input {
  display: none;
}

label.custom-radio input+div {
  content: "\a";
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

label.custom-radio input:checked+div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-radio"><input type="radio"><div></div></label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/uYZM2/

Comment: Пробую Ваше решение реализовать на хроме - результат элемент размером 0х0 - как можно "заполнить" элемент?

Comment: ну я же дал fiddle, там все элементы 20x20

Comment: Да Спасибо, мои ошибки были - пытался div засунуть в input, а не lable и ошибся в пути к иконкам)

Answer (score 4):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

.custom-radios [type='radio'] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100vw;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #3498db;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #f1c40f;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #e74c3c;
}
.custom-radios [type='radio'] + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2017/check-icn.svg") 50%/50% no-repeat;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  content: '';
}
.custom-radios [type='radio']:checked + label:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="custom-radios">
  <input type="radio" name="c" id="c0" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="c0">c0</label>
  <input type="radio" name="c" id="c1"/>
  <label for="c1">c1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="c" id="c2"/>
  <label for="c2">c2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="c" id="c3"/>
  <label for="c3">c3</label>
</div>
</body>
```

У радио кнопки в активном (checked) состоянии показывается фон, в качестве которого выступает svg файл - галочка.