# Как сверстать такой input radio?

Tags: html, css

Как получить такой input **radio** на css ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/255084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать `radial-gradient`:

```css
input { display: none; }

label {
  margin: 12px 7px 12px 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 117px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ADB4BB;
  font: 18px/45px 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  color: #8D9399;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 22px 50%, transparent 11px, #ADB4BB 12px, #ADB4BB 13px, transparent 14px);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 22px 50%, #ADB4BB 13px, transparent 14px);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes"><label for="yes">ДА</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no"><label for="no">НЕТ</label>
```

Или так:

```css
input { display: none; }

label {
  margin: 12px 7px 12px 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 117px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ADB4BB;
  font: 18px/45px 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  color: #8D9399;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 22px 50%, transparent 11px, #ADB4BB 12px, #ADB4BB 13px, transparent 14px);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 22px 50%, #4B91C8 9px, transparent 11px, #ADB4BB 12px, #ADB4BB 13px, transparent 14px);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" checked><label for="yes">ДА</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no"><label for="no">НЕТ</label>
```

Comment: Хороший, добротный ответ!

Answer (score 5):

Вот так можно:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}

#yes:checked ~ [for="yes"],
#no:checked ~ [for="no"] {
  background-color: gray;
}

[for="yes"]::after {
  content: 'ДА';
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
}

[for="no"]::after {
  content: 'НЕТ';
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: -38px;
}

[for="yes"]::before,
[for="no"]::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -90px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" />
<label for="yes"></label>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" />
<label for="no"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой `input type="radio"` можно создать если обернуть `input` в тег `label` и написать несколько строк `css`. 

Кастомизировать именно кружок у `radio button` нельзя, для этого надо его сделать невидимым, и стилизировать `span` находящийся внутри тега `label`

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked ~ .custom-radio {
  background-color: #999;
}

.custom-radio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes-no"/>
  ДА
  <span class="custom-radio"></span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes-no"/>
  НЕТ
  <span class="custom-radio"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: тут меня больше интересует стилизация самого кружка))

Comment: @Денис я изменил ответ, теперь стилизуется сам кружок